# Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, connection-string

I am getting this error when I try to insert record in db.
`Microsoft OLE DB` Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

`[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]` Data source name not found and no default driver specified

my connection is :

```
Application("Db_ConnectionString")= "DSN=dsnname;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;"
```

please help me asap.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your  answers.

I myself fixed the error. Assigned wrong dsn name in my code. 
I changed it and now its working fine

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles across this: I got this error on Windows Server 2012 when migrating a legacy ASP app - I had to enabled 32-bit applications in the AppPool's advanced settings.

Comment: @IanRoutledge - I stumbled across this and resolved the error as described - did you want to add this as an answer?

Comment: @IanRoutledge, if you would post your comment as an answer, I'd like to vote it up.

Comment: I had to add Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; to my connection in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error on Windows Server 2012 when migrating a legacy ASP app - I had to enabled 32-bit applications in the AppPool's advanced setting

Comment: Thanks this saved me after many hours of wondering what was wrong with my connection string while in actuality it was 32bit applications being set to false in IIS Application pool! Thanks AGAIN!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup "dsnname" in ODBC?  Should be in *Adminitrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC)* under the *System DSN* tab.

Answer (score 0):

this problem can be solve using **install jdk 7** to download go 
to below link

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
>
> Java SE Development Kit 7u79

Product / File Description : Windows x86
Size: 138.31 MB
Download: jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe